# Cloth modifier stops working after applying

Tags: cloth-simulation

[image: Image of modifier not working]

I am a noob in blender and the cloth modifier stops working after applying to a path(noodle) converted to a mesh. It's not working on the cylinder and 2 cubes after applying. Have removed cloth modifier, applied scale and reassigned modifier, deleted mesh and did a new one all to no avail.

Another mesh with the modifier moves slower when animating(the corn). What could be the problem?
The links are to the files are above.

[image: Image of modifier working]

[Modifier working](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MRuR3asKXgEWPMdyvZg9NasbplMc3AnB/view?usp=sharing)

[Modifier not working](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gufr2mSu-5r1R_fN2NyVR09nrg7DAkU3/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is unanswerable and was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Risking stating the obvious, only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly you alone know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Describe the issue in detail, add [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) of relevant settings and user interface, with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for reopening review.

Comment: Please reopen the question as it has been closed. Was offline due to personal reasons and have added relevant links to the blend file. Thanks.